# Google map API does not plot on different continents

Tags: javascript, html, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have used the google map API to plot a way point on google map

I referred to the the following page:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions

'Using Waypoints in Routes section' and modified it a bit so as to plot only 3 points on the map.
The following is my javascript code.

```
var directionDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;

function initialize() {
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var initialloc = new google.maps.LatLng(12.971599, 77.594563);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom : 6,
        mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center : initialloc
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    calcRoute();

}

function calcRoute() {
    var lat = new Array();
    var lon = new Array();

    var start = new google.maps.LatLng(12.971599,77.594563);
    var mid = new google.maps.LatLng(12.971558,77.594552);
    var end = new google.maps.LatLng(12.971558,77.594552);

    var waypts = [];
    waypts.push( {
        location : mid,
        stopover : true
    });


    var request = {
        origin : start,
        destination : end,
        waypoints : waypts,
        optimizeWaypoints : true,
        travelMode : google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(
                    request,
                    function(response, status) {
                        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                            var route = response.routes[0];

                        }
                    });

}
```

which works perfectly fine if the 3 locations are within same country, ie they have a road map.

My question is how to plot the map when the location are in different continents eg India and Australia?

Can anyone please help.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why would you expect to be able to get driving directions from India to Australia?

Comment: If your goal is to draw a polyline between two continents, the directions service (which returns "directions") is the wrong thing to use.  Use a google.maps.Polyline.

Comment: i  need to plot inter and intra continents. Is there any way

Comment: Yes there is a way.  But it will depend on what your requirements are.  If you need driving directions, then you will need to write code to use driving directions on land, and polylines over water/between continents.  If you don't need driving directions (you don't need the polylines to follow roads), just use polylines. [Simple example](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple) from the documentation.

Comment: Yes I have seen the example. Can you merge polylines with driving directions?

Comment: Driving directions return [polylines, or at least the array of coordinates needed to draw them](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_directions_custom_iconsC.html).  You can add additional coordinates to those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not about different continents, but whether the routing engine's database has information about all the countries between your start and endpoints, including car ferries. You can see that the same occurs in maps.google.com . [Here's an intercontinental route](https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Bergev%C3%A4gen&daddr=MSH%203&hl=en&ie=UTF8&sll=28.304381,43.945313&sspn=142.933439,321.679688&geocode=FXIfsQMd7K7DAA;FWK3NQEdchSnBA&mra=dme&mrsp=1&sz=2&t=m&z=2) from Europe to India, but if you try to move the B marker to the US or Canada, it doesn't get a route because it doesn't know a ferry across the Atlantic.
You can see what countries have coverage in [this spreadsheet](http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/mapcoverage_filtered.html).