# Find out distance between two points using Google map API based on medium (Road,Air,Ship)?

Tags: google-maps, distance

I am working on Google Map API. My Question is, can I find Distance between two point based on medium like

- By Road
- By Air
- By Ship

Actually, I get distance between two points. There are no any problem. It works fine for me.

I Need Something like this :

**Example** : if I want to go from India to America, then i have three ways to reach at place.

`By Road` `By Air` `By Ship`.

- Now if I select **By Road** then it should be return total Number of days for Journey. like **20 days**.
- Now if I select **By Air** then it should be return total Number of days for Journey. like **5 days**.
- Now if I select **By Ship** then it should be return total Number of days for Journey. like  **15 days**.

It should also show different way point in map as per Medium change.

So, is it possible to do like this way? I have already worked in Google Map API but this is Challenging task for me.

Hope, you people will help me.

Comment: Everything is possible but, what have you tried?

Comment: i have R&d in Google map developer. i also check google map browser to get direction column. if i pass two points (rajkot to mumbai) that shows me distance by road and by walk . but if i pass (mumbai to america) then show's message like "We could not calculate directions between Mumbai, Maharashtra and New York, NY, USA.
". so, based on that i am confused. because rajkot to mumbai both are in India where mumbai to america are two different country.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792801/google-map-api-does-not-plot-on-different-continents/11793388#11793388

Comment: Thank you sir, Its really helpful for me. i read that google document in that there are one tag regarding travel mode in that there are only 4 ways to get distance between two points.there are no ship mode and air mode . so i can get only by road ? now what i can do for air mode and ship mode ? can you guide me what is TRANSIT  mode ? i did not get clearly . Again Thank you very much sir.

Comment: TRANSIT mode is public transportation, (buses, trains, subways). There are no ships or planes in the routing engine.

Comment: Again Thank you sir, i had read about region that if region have not determine direction then it will return "zero result". its true. thanks lot.